# How can I debug Windows UWP apps in parallels?

Tags: visual-studio, parallels, xamarin.uwp

When I try to debug my UWP project from Visual Studio 2017 running in Windows 10 in a parallels instance, it always errors out that it cannot find the AppxManifest:
`DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CF0] error 0x80070003: Opening file from location: AppxManifest.xml failed with error: The system cannot find the path specified`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps to resolve this issue are as follows:

1. Unload the UWP project (Right-click on project and then select "Unload Project")
2. Edit the project file in VS (Right-click on unloaded project and then select "Edit ...")
3. Find an XML entry for the OutputPath. For instance the entry for OutputPath when building for Debug|x86 should look like bin/x86/Debug. Notice that the entry contains relative path.
4. Edit the path to an absolute path on one of VMs drives. For instance, to set the path to the C:\UWPBuilds\x86\Debug directory.
5. Close the project file
6. Reload the project (Right-click on unloaded project and then select "Reload Project").

Answer mostly based on discussion found here: https://forum.parallels.com/threads/prlsf-permissions-issue-when-developing-an-uwp-app-in-visual-studio.342549/